# What do square brackets after a function reference mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, javascript-objects

I just spent about 15 minutes debugging a piece of JavaScript code, and discovered the problem was that I had written

```
matches.push[[-1]];
```

instead of

```
matches.push([[-1]]);
```

like I intended, where `matches` is an array. Can somebody explain to me why JavaScript didn’t throw a syntax error on the former, and what its meaning is?

Answer (score 3):

#### Why

`matches.push` is a [`Function Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), and you can [access object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) and methods through dot notation or the bracket notation. Basically you're asking for something which isn't in the `push` [`Function Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), so it yields `undefined`.

[image]

#### Note

If you added something with the key `[-1]` as in `matches[[-1]] = "something"` it would also be valid, so the syntax *is* valid, simply not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

Its just a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
var matches = [];
matches.push[1] = 'bla'
document.write(matches.push[1]);
```

Basically you do the following:

```
matches.push[[-1]];
```

resolves to (a single number in brackets becomes a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)) and while the [accessor for objects is a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names), you get

```
matches.push['-1']
```

and that resolves to

```
undefined
```

because the property `'-1'` is undefined.

Comment: Oha..! interesting... gotto check this on console...  `var matches = []; matches.push[2] = "two"; console.log(matches);<- [] // wtf`..?

Comment: you are assigning to matches.push, not matches, please see the example above with `run code`.

Comment: Well i would normally won't do this ever but since mentioned i did and...  whatever... well what's all about that the square brackets and push touch each other..? Is this proper JS..? I am not being sarcastic...

Comment: it is valid JS and while the access to a property which not exist is valid (stil returning `undefined`) there is not exception.

Comment: @ Nina Scholz: if you say so... respect..! but come on... `var arr = [1,2,3,4]; arr.push["-4"] ; arr; <- [1,2,3,4]` ... VM ignores means being valid? Yet i haven't got yet why i got no complaints from the VM though. Even if true there should be absolutely no use of this functionality. Well i suppose..

Comment: `arr.push["-4"]` is an access, not an assignment.

Comment: What sober mind in the world would name an object property as "push" and make it an array..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110439/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-redu).

Answer (score 1):

Everything in js is an object, even a function. I imagine the engine just referenced a (nonexistent) field to the `push` function/object. That results in `undefined`.